# Unable to use constant

Tags: php, constants

I am working on some PHP code and I am trying to create an initialize.php file to define my site root and my includes folder so I can include one file on each page instead of many.  When I include my initialize.php file and then try to use a constant from that file such as LIB_PATH I get an error that it is an undefined constant.  Below is the contents of the initialize file.

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'Users'.DS.'Andy'.DS.'sites'.DS.'sandbox'.DS.'photo_gallery');
defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."functions.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."session.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."database.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."user.php");
```

I have also noticed that if I try to use LIB_PATH in one of these files I am requiring it will throw an error that the constant is undefined.  I am relatively new to PHP but my assumption was that by defining the constant I would be able to use it in any of these files.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : wt is this?? is there any code missing??

Comment: Is that the real code or a rewrite for the post?

Comment: @bhushya - See next line.

Comment: This is the code I have in my initialize.php file.  The only thing missing is the <?php ?> tags.  The issue I am having is in my database.php file the first line is `require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'config.php');`.  That is the line of code that is throwing the error.  I tried commenting out that line but then my database.php file doesn't get the constants defined in config.php.

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong in the code you've shared. If that's your main script, `config` should happily inherit all the constants you've defined.

Comment: I can suggest you run [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) right before the line that triggers the error message.

Comment: can you post the error here??

Comment: I figured out what the issue was...I updated my index.php file with the new initialize file I made, but I was going to the index.php file I have in my admin folder and not the one I updated.  This is what happens when I don't have my coffee yet.  Thank you for your quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment says, "in my database.php file the first line is

```
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'config.php');
```

Well, that won't work. You must explicitly include your `initialize.php` before you can use the constants you define there.

To do the kind of thing you are trying to do, `initialize.php` should be `include`d before you do anything else on each and every page where you will need those constants.